# Excel Source validation error not firing Data Flow task fail event

Tags: ssis

I have a package with a Data Flow task containing Excel Source. DelayValidation is set to True for the Data Flow.

There is an event handler OnTaskFailed at package level. However if the Excel Source validaton fails the OnTaskFailed handler does not execute. It seems the validation error does not fire Task Failed event.

Is it possible to configure it to fire the Task Failed event?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, instead of setting up at the package level, you should set it at the data flow task level. What I mean is, in the `event handler` pane you can change the executable to the certain `data flow task`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I would like to keep the event handler at package level, so it can execute if any of the tasks fails.